# get age using year of birth only on perl

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

i have a mysql table called subscribers like this:

```
cell    |name        |year|id|email
10000000|Arabang,GP|F|1981|2|10000000@cs.ub.bw
10000001|Basupang,B.|F|1981|42|10000001@cs.ub.bw
10000002|Bontshitswe,C.|F|1980|36|10000002@cs.ub.bw
10000003|Botsalano,T.|M|1980|42|10000003@cs.ub.bw
10000004|Botshelo,M.|F|1982|14|10000004@cs.ub.bw
10000005|Botshelo,OD|M|1981|10|10000005@cs.ub.bw
10000006|Chabota,M|M|1980|3|10000006@cs.ub.bw
```

how do i calculate age  using the year only .i have researched [on this website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) 
 but still i cant understand how to do that.
**the data type of year is year **

here is my query :

```
my $sth0 =$dbh-> prepare("select *,(  2014 - year)
                          as year  from subscribers 
                          ");

$sth0->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: John was born in 1964. Is he 49 or 50? *(hint: there's no way to know)*

Comment: "how do i calculate age using the year only"  You can't.

Comment: what if i change the data type of year to int,can it be possible @andy

Comment: Look at the previous comment: If someone is born in 1964, is he 49 or 50?  If he was born in January 1964, and it's currently April 2014, then he's 50.  If he was born in December 1964, then he's 49.  **You cannot tell someone's age knowing only the year of their birth and the current year.**

Comment: You can only calculate minimum age or maximum age, so think out what is more likely to be the case needed from the requirements and calculate that.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error? Do you have wrong results? At the moment, it looks to me, as if you have trouble substracting the values, right? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what your question is. Why do you think that this doesn't work? If you ignore the fact that the age you get this way might be a year too high (depending on when the person's birthday is) then your query works.

```
[test]> create table person (name varchar(20), birth year);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

[test]> insert into person values ('Dave', 1962);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

[test]> select name, year(now()) - birth as age from person;
+------+------+
| name | age  |
+------+------+
| Dave |   52 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

(And that's a year too high, as my birthday is in September and it's only April now.)

**Note:** I changed your hard-coded '2014' to `year(now())` so the query continues to work the same way in the future.

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT. I'm really not sure how I helped. I only demonstrated that you existing code was already working.